# Add Custom Declaration in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Is there any way that I can add custom declaration in xml using java.

(i.e) I created xml using dom parser in Java.  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF_8"?>` has been created by default.

I want another declaration is also need to be added in my xml. `<?myxml version="10.0"?>`

Is there any way I could achieve this in dom parser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you serializing the DOM to a stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML terms `<?myxml .... ?>` (or any similar construct within `<?  ?>` but *not* named `<?xml`) is called a *processing instruction*, and can go anywhere in the document (except inside a start or end element tag).  The bit between the opening `<?` and the first following whitespace character - "myxml" in this example - is the PI *target*, and everything after the first block of whitespace up to the closing `?>` is the PI *data*.

You can create a PI in the DOM using `document.createProcessingInstruction`, and add the resulting node to an appropriate place in the document.  For example to put it before the start tag of the document element you could say

```
ProcessingInstruction newPI = document.createProcessingInstruction(
                                             "myxml", "version=\"10.0\"");
document.insertBefore(newPI, document.getDocumentElement());
```

Note that the `<?xml ...?>` declaration itself is *not* a processing instruction, even though it has the same format, and it is not represented as a `ProcessingInstruction` node in the DOM tree.

Comment: And the `<?xml?>` declaration can be [omitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#OMIT_XML_DECLARATION) from a transformer output using `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");`